# Jquery generated with PHP duplicate events for error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

In summary, I have a search engine "index.php" that through a JQuery script ($ post) brings a set of forms. The HTML and JQuery of the form is generated by PHP in the $ post response.

Every time I do a search in index.php the form events are automatically duplicated.
I tried many things but I still can't fix it.

```
        index.php (JQuery Script:)

          $("[name='txtBuscar']").keyup(function(){

          $("[name='container']").html("<img src='/cargando.gif' class='img-fluid' style='display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; margin-top:18%;'>");

          $.post("/form.php", 
            {

              txtBuscar:$("#txtBuscar").val()

            },
            function(data, status){

              $("[name='container']").html(data);

            });
          });
```

The other file:

```
form.php

<?php  echo '
<button name="caca" class="caca" type="button">Click Me!</button>     
<script>
      $(\'.container\').on(\'click\', \'.caca\', function (){        
        alert("caca ");        
      });
</script>';
?>
```

[The generated HTML with duplicated events:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rpom.png)

Comment: We need the generated HTML to know the problem. Guessing there are multiple `.caca` elements so event delegation is causing multiple event handlers for same element.

Comment: Thanks .caca is only in the HTML document.

Comment: Show us an example of the duplication you are talking about.

Comment: The alert("caca"); run the times that i did the search on index.php

Comment: You need to demonstrate how to problem is produced and what is happening in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the PHP response, it executes this script and installs a new handler, without removing the previous one:

```
  $(\'.container\').on(\'click\', \'.caca\', function (){        
    alert("caca ");        
  });
```

You must either verify that the handler is already in place and, if so, not reinstall again (this you do if the handler is always the same):

```
 if (!window.hasOwnProperty('handlerContainer')) {
     window.handlerContainer = true;
     $('.container').on('click', ...
 }
```

or each time remove the old handler and reinstall the new:

```
 $('.container').off('click', '.caca').on('click', '.caca', ...
```

In general, if at all possible, **never** run scripts from a page loaded from AJAX. You *can*, but in my experience it's asking for several different kinds of troubles. You can reference already-loaded callbacks instead:

```
 $.post('/some/url')
  .then(reply => {


      if (reply.call) {
          if (window.hasOwnProperty(reply.call)) {
              window[reply.call].apply(this, reply.arguments || null);
          }
      }
  }
```

and the POST reply in this case would be a JSON object:

```
  print json_encode([
      'status'     => 'success',
      'call'       => 'someFunction',
      'arguments'  => [ 1, 2, "Hello" ]
  ]);
```

I have developed a simple library that allows me to pass, say, '@window.somevariable' or '@this.property.with.subproperty' or '$(selector)' from PHP, and have it properly decoded client side. You could do the same.

Comment: If i never run scripts from ajax, how i can do it works? Regards.